# cast VARCHAR2 to LONG,RAW,CLOB and find HASH md5

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, hash

There is a table A with fields `(str1 VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),str2 VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR))`

There is a table B with fields `(str1 VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),str2 VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),hash_code NUMBER)`

```
begin
insert into B(str1,str2,hash_code)
select str1, str2, standart_hash(str1 ||str2,'MD5') as hash_code from A;
commit;
end;
```

As a result there is an exception when `length(str1||str2)` is longer than 4000 (varchar2 is too small).

How can I cast this to other type like `clob` in such select? `to_clob(str1 || str2)` does not work.

And `standart_hash` does not work with `clob,long,raw`.

What can I use to solve this after solving problem with casting?

Comment: What error are you getting? I was able to execute your insert with no problem. The varchar2 data type in PL/SQL has a max length of 32768 bytes, and standard_hash has no limit on the input length. The limit of 4000 characters only applies to table columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The varchar2 datatype actually has a max length of 32K in PL/SQL, and standard_hash has no limit on the size of the input. Also note that standard_hash returns the RAW datatype, not NUMBER as you have the hash_code column defined in your example.

```
SQL> desc A
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 STR1                           VARCHAR2(4000)
 STR2                           VARCHAR2(4000)

SQL> desc B
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 STR1                           VARCHAR2(4000)
 STR2                           VARCHAR2(4000)
 HASH_VALUE                     RAW(50)

SQL> select length(str1), length(str2) from A;

LENGTH(STR1) LENGTH(STR2)
------------ ------------
        4000         4000
           3            3

SQL> insert into B (str1, str2, hash_value) select str1, str2, standard_hash(str1||str2,'MD5') as hash_value from A;

2 rows created.

SQL> begin
  2  insert into B (str1, str2, hash_value) select str1, str2, standard_hash(str1||str2,'MD5') as hash_value from A;
  3  commit;
  4  end;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

As you can see, I was able to run your example with no problem.

Comment: Is it length in bytes?
What about there will be 2 varchar2 with 3000 chars?

Comment: The 4000 byte limit only applies to database columns, not PL/SQL constructs. There the limit is 32K, so there is no issue concatenating two 4000 byte strings in PL/SQL. Put another way, "str1 || str2" will never be more than 8000 bytes - well within the 32K limit. As long as you don't try to insert that value back into a varchar2 column in a table you won't have any problems.